# Testing server's response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get

I have a form in my angular app in which user are required to provide a valid url.
Therefore when submitting the form, I'd like to test if the URL is valid by making a get request to the url provided and check if the server sends 200.

When a click the submit button, the following code is run:

```
$http.get(scope.target_url).success(function(){
                // some code 
            }).error(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            });
```

However, I never get a successfull answer:
- if I provide a url like: 'http://www.somesite.com', I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'http://www.somesite.com'. Received an invalid response. Origin 'mydomain' is therefore not allowed access.
```

- if I provide a url like: 'http://somesite.com', I get:

  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://somesite.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'mydomain' is therefore not allowed access.

Where does the problem come from?

Comment: This is because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). You'd need to make the request from your server rather than client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal security constraints. Read about CORS here:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin%5fresource%5fsharing)